# Write a variable to a file in Python

Tags: python, templates, file-handling, memory-efficient

Lets say I have a python function which takes input of name, age, gender etc from the user I have a template from which I read and I have to write. For eg I have the following input:

```
Name: Ashish
Age: 22
Gender: Male
Profession: Software Engineer
```

I have a template with many lines in the form of:

```
Hi, Name
Your age is Age and you are Gender working as a Profession.....
```

I want to read from the template and write to a new file and add the variables to the output file dynamically without using the replace function is it possible to get output as this (for example):

```
Hi, Ashish
Your age is 22 and you are Male working as a Software Engineer.....
```

I don't want to use replace function but want to read from the template file and write the variables dynamically to the output file. Help will be appreciated. I am working on the automation task for which I require reading from file. This is just an example:)

Comment: Which part are you struggling with?  File Read?  File Write?  Assigning values to a variable?  The question is a little broad.  This is a homework problem which isn't what SO is about.  If you take a stab and still have issues, this is the place to come to.  Show us an honest attempt and ideally a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and we will be happy to help.

Comment: Start with the Python tutorial to learn how to write a function definition.

Answer (score 1):

```
def write_to_file(name,age,gender,profession):
     message = "Hi {} \nYour age is {} and you are {} working as a 
           {}".format(name,age,gender,profession)
     return message

line = write_to_file("Janvi",20,"female","teacher")
my_file = open("file.txt","w")
my_file.writelines(line)
```

Comment: Hi Pooja, just one minor change. When using multiple lines (as passed in the variable message), it is better to use triple double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can modify the template file, you can use .format() on the template file once loaded in as a string.

```
def template_values(name, age, gender, profession):
    return "Hi {name}, Your age is {age} and you are {gender} working as a {profession}.....".format(
        name=name,
        age=age,
        gender=gender,
        profession=profession
    )
```

Comment: I am reading the template from a file and I don't want to copy the whole text  and write it in return

Comment: You can use the {variable} formatting in the file itself, and then just read it in as a string. It will still work.